# como obtener el id de un nodo con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nodos

tengo la siguiente linea de `HTML` que es una tabla. en esta tabla tengo un `<tr>` el cual tiene un `id`. ademas tengo una función que captura llamada `transformarEnEditable` por la cual paso el `tr` para obtener los valores de los `td` y editarlos. la linea es la siguiente:

```
 $('#lista_direcciones').append('<tr id="' + direccion.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + direccionCompletaEdit(direccion, data.localidad) + '</td>' +
                                '<td style="text-align: center">' +
                                '' + esActual(direccion.es_actual) + '</td>' +
                                '' +
                                '<td class="btn-group"  style="text-align: center;">' +
                                '<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil blue" onclick=" transformarEnEditable(this, id_miembro) " title="Editar Ocupaci&oacute;n Laboral"></button><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash red" onclick="eliminarDireccion(\'' + direccion.id_count + '\');"></buton></td></tr>');
```

y mi funcion `transformarEnEditable` es la siguiente:

```
function transformarEnEditable(nodo, id){

        id_venta = id;

        alert(id);

        if (editando == false) {

            var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD

            var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

            var id_nodo = nodo.parent().parent().attr('id');

            var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

             lugar_trabajo = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
             ocupacion_laboral = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;

            var nuevoCodigoHtml =

                '<tr id="actual">'+
                '<td >'+ lugar_trabajo +'</td>' +

                '<td class="align-center"><label><input id="direccion_anterior" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-4"><span class="lbl middle"></span></label></td>' +

                '<td class="align-center"><a onclick="capturarEnvio()" class="green" title="Aceptar">' +
                '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120"></i></a> ' +
                '<a onclick="anular()" class="red" title="Cancelar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-close bigger-120"></i></a></td>'+
                '</tr>';

            nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;


            if(ocupacion_laboral === 'Es Actual'){
                $("#direccion_anterior").prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#direccion_anterior").prop('checked', false);
            }

            editando = "true";
        }
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo obtener el `id` del `tr` y pasarselo a la funcion `capturarEnvio()` para salvar dicho `id`

Comment: No sé si entiendo lo que quieres hacer, pero todo elemento HTML tiene un atributo id: `nodoTr.id` tendrá el identificador de ese elemento `<tr>`

Comment: si lo tiene, en la pregunta lo tengo identificado

Answer (score 1):

La función que se lanza por un evento, recibe como parámetro el evento en sí. De ahí puedes obtener el elemento sobre el que se produjo el evento, su elemento padre... y lo que necesites:

```js
function getIdPadre(event) {
  const elem=event.target;
  console.log('Pulsado el botón',elem.innerText);
  debugger;
  console.log('El ID de su padre es',elem.parentElement.id);
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click',getIdPadre);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <button>Div 1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <button>Div 2</button>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <button>Div 3</button>
</div>
```